# Move div up to other div

Tags: html, css, css-float, position

I have a set of divs which are generated dynamically. I have set there width but the height is different each time. I have given the divs `float:left` The problem is that they don't position right under each other. The form rows and the div with the biggest height is the height of the row. This is leaving a lot of space between divs (vertically)

Please take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpw3f/1/)

How do I get the div that says "move this div up" stick under the div1?

Comment: You may be looking for http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Another solution could be to use `display:inline-block`

Comment: @daniel No it doesn't work for my script

Comment: depends which changes are allowed: http://jsfiddle.net/Mpw3f/2/

Comment: you cant use display: inline?

Comment: @Eric No doesn't work for me, maybe because the divs are created dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the heights of your divs are static (unlikely, I know), you can add a negative `margin-top` to the div you want to move up.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/2TEZA/).

For dynamically created divs, your best bet will probably be a third party plugin (as I mentioned in my comment above) like jquery masonry, or something similar.